# UIPropertyAnimator causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I'm experiencing a strange crash caused by `UIPropertyAnimtor`. I have `UICollectionView` with custom layout (for strechy header), and I'm using `UIPropertyAnimator` for animating blur when `UICollectionView` is pulled down.

Problem is, when I dismiss a scene (sometimes after I push it again), application crashes with following message:

```
objc[11346]: Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x121eeda60) of class [APPLICATION_NAME].StrechyHeaderCollectionReusableView. It is possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.
```

[image]

When I go back incode on what caused the crash, its the call in `deinit`. Anyway, the way I understand `UIPropertyAnimator` it's done right. Without !animator.stopAnimation(true)`the app would crash due to unreleased`UIProperyAnimator`.

[image]

This is code in my header view:

```
final class StrechyHeaderCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView, Nibable {

    // some code...

    lazy var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator = {
        UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 3.0, curve: .easeOut, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.blurVisualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        })
    }()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        blurVisualEffectView.effect = nil
    }

    // some code...

    deinit {
        animator.stopAnimation(true)
    }
}
```

I'm changing animaiton fraction from a data source + delegate class, and visual effect view is inside custom header xib.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // some code...

    let strechyHeader = headerView(in: collectionView)
    strechyHeader?.isBackButtonHidden = isBackButtonHidden

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        strechyHeader?.animator.fractionComplete = 0
    } else {
        strechyHeader?.animator.fractionComplete = abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y) / 100
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `finishAnimation` in your deinitialization method:

```swift
guard animator.state == .active else { return }
animator.stopAnimation(false)
animator.finishAnimation(at: .start)
```

**UPD:**

Try to not use lazy animator:

```swift
 private var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(
               duration: 3.0,
               curve: .easeOut,
               animations: { [weak self] in
                   self?.blurVisualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
               })
        blurVisualEffectView.effect = nil
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunatelly still crashing.

Comment: can you please share how do you starting animation and how do you initialize your blurVisualEffectView ?

Comment: Hm, actually weak and lazy do not mix well. Please try to make your animator as a **non-lazy stored property**. I've updated my answer